# Backlog search: what fields does it actually search?

Tags: jira

I'm confused about the Search box at the top of the Backlog view.  This one:

[image: Jira backlog search box]

I always thought that this box searched *everything* - all fields.  But from an accidental test - then repeated more carefully - I'm finding that it in fact only searches the issue Summary, Issue Key (and possibly some other fields).

To reproduce:

1. Create an issue, with summary "Green" and description "Purple".
2. Type "Green" in the search box: issue appears in filtered backlog.
3. Type "Purple" in the search box: issue *doesn't* appear in filtered backlog.

How can I even find out what this search box does?  Or alter what it does, ideally?  Because this makes avoiding duplicate issues pretty difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This box is searching through Name (Summary), Code (Issue Key) and Assignee and sadly there's no customization on that as mentioned [in this ticket](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-70116).